# Is there a definition of an $\infty$-groupoid in HoTT whose terms are $n$-manifolds and whose higher morphisms are diffeomorphisms/isotopies/etc?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, topological-quantum-field-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Suppose you want to work with TQFTs in homotopy type theory (HoTT). Working with $(\infty,n)$-categories, or even $(\infty,1)$-categories, is something that I gather is too difficult for HoTT at the moment because of coherence issues. However, you could just forget all noninvertible cobordisms, and you should be able to obtain an $\infty$-groupoid from your $(\infty,1)$-category of cobordisms. Then you could try to define functions from this $\infty$-groupoid to other $\infty$-groupoids, ideally inspired by TQFT invariants.

Is there an inductive definition in HoTT of such a "groupoid of manifolds?" I'd also be happy with something like an $\infty$-groupoid of knots in $S^3$.

Comment: One motivation for this question is the existence of naturality results for Heegaard Floer homology (http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4996) and related theories. One could at least try to reformulate such results in the language of higher groupoids, and HoTT seems like an enticing possibility for doing this cleanly.

Comment: Do you mean in HoTT or in some interpretation of HoTT?

Comment: I'd prefer in HoTT itself- something inductively defined and thus (ideally) easy to work with.

Comment: Maybe there's some formulation in cohesive HoTT (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohesive+homotopy+type+theory) . However as I understand this is done inside an infinity topos.

Comment: Cohesive HoTT seems very interesting for working with manifolds, but to me it looks like it's doing something a bit different: working with types which themselves can be interpreted as (like) smooth manifolds. I think my question is slightly different: I want a type whose terms stand for smooth manifolds, but which itself might not need any sort of smooth structure.

Comment: For knots, the naive picture I have would go something like this: a knot is either the unknot, or obtained from another knot by some inductive process (e.g. replacing two strands with a crossing, or something). Identities between knots would be inductively generated by the Reidemeister moves. I'm not sure how you get identities between identities between identities, etc- it seems possible to write down generating identites at each level but it just keeps getting more complicated.

Comment: The cobordism hypothesis (as Lurie works with it) tells us exactly what the cobordism oo-category is: it's freely generated [blah blah blah]. That would be a good starting point.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: The OP discards all noninvertible bordisms, which results in a vastly different category than Lurie's.

Comment: @Dmitri the OP said you 'could' throw away non-invertible bordisms. But is this what is really wanted? I would argue defining the full thing by a universal property would be better. If the fully groupoidal version also has a universal property, then I would say use that.

Comment: I agree that it would be better to have a full version, but besides the relevant category theory I'm also looking for something that could be formalized in HoTT. As I understand it, there are coherence issues involved with defining even $(\infty,1)$-categories in HoTT, e.g. the MO question ["How do you define (infinity,1) categories in Homotopy Type Theory?"](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145770/how-do-you-define-infinity-1-categories-in-homotopy-type-theory?rq=1)